# Access Using XSLT to import XML

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, foreach

I'm currently working on new code on Access that I can't seem to wrap my head around. I'm very new to xslt and I understand the basic concepts of "For-Each" but I am still having trouble with it. I was hoping if some of you guys can help me understand why my code isn't working how it is suppose to.

What I was hoping for is to print all of this in tables in Access with having all Branch names in separate rows. Currently I have the branch names printed in a single row.

Anything helps. Thank you guys!

XSLT Code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<ING_PNA_Import>
  <xsl:for-each select="PNAResponse/PriceAndAvailability">
    <Import>

      <Test>
        <SKU>
          <xsl:value-of select="@SKU"/>
        </SKU>
        <VendorNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="VendorNumber"/>
        </VendorNumber>
        <Price>
          <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
        </Price>
        <MPN>
          <xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerPartNumber"/>
        </MPN>

          <ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="Branch/@ID"/>
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
        </ID>

        <Name>

          <xsl:for-each select="Branch">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
          </xsl:for-each>`
        </Name>

        <Availability>
          <xsl:value-of select="Branch/Availability"/>
        </Availability>

      </Test>

    </Import>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ING_PNA_Import>
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<PNAResponse>
<Version>2.0</Version>
<TransactionHeader>
  <SenderID>YOU</SenderID>
  <ReceiverID>MD</ReceiverID>
  <ErrorStatus ErrorNumber=""></ErrorStatus>
  <DocumentID></DocumentID>
  <TransactionID></TransactionID>
</TransactionHeader>

<PriceAndAvailability SKU="100150" Quantity="1">
  <Price>21.21</Price>
  <SpecialPriceFlag></SpecialPriceFlag>
  <ManufacturerPartNumber>TEST1234</ManufacturerPartNumber>
  <ManufacturerPartNumberOccurs></ManufacturerPartNumberOccurs>
  <VendorNumber>123X</VendorNumber>
  <Description>Cool Item</Description>
  <ReserveInventoryFlag>Y</ReserveInventoryFlag>
  <AvailableRebQty>0</AvailableRebQty>

  <Branch Name="Town1" ID="01">
    <Availability>8</Availability>
    <OnOrder>0</OnOrder>
    <ETADate></ETADate>
  </Branch>

  <Branch Name="Town2" ID="02">
    <Availability>8</Availability>
    <OnOrder>0</OnOrder>
    <ETADate></ETADate>
  </Branch>

  <Branch Name="Town3" ID="03">
    <Availability>6</Availability>
    <OnOrder>5</OnOrder>
    <ETADate></ETADate>
  </Branch>

  <Branch Name="Town4" ID="04">
    <Availability>5</Availability>
    <OnOrder>5</OnOrder>
    <ETADate></ETADate>
  </Branch>

  <Branch Name="Town5" ID="05">
    <Availability>10</Availability>
    <OnOrder>0</OnOrder>
    <ETADate></ETADate>
  </Branch>

  <UPC>123456789012345</UPC>
  <CustomerPartNumber></CustomerPartNumber>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply nest your `<Name>` node within the Branch `<xsl:for-each>` to achieve multiple child nodes:

**Previous**

```
  <Name>
     <xsl:for-each select="Branch">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
     </xsl:for-each>`
  </Name>
```

**Updated**

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Branch">
     <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
     </Name>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ING_PNA_Import>
  <Import>
    <Test>
      <SKU>100150</SKU>
      <VendorNumber>123X</VendorNumber>
      <Price>21.21</Price>
      <MPN>TEST1234</MPN>
      <ID>01</ID>
      <Name>Town1</Name>
      <Name>Town2</Name>
      <Name>Town3</Name>
      <Name>Town4</Name>
      <Name>Town5</Name>
      <Availability>8</Availability>
    </Test>
  </Import>
</ING_PNA_Import>
```

However, in MS Access, like most databases, you require distinct column names, so consider suffixing with a number, namely the node's position:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Branch">
   <xsl:element name="{concat('Name', position())}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ING_PNA_Import>
  <Import>
    <Test>
      <SKU>100150</SKU>
      <VendorNumber>123X</VendorNumber>
      <Price>21.21</Price>
      <MPN>TEST1234</MPN>
      <ID>01</ID>
      <Name1>Town1</Name1>
      <Name2>Town2</Name2>
      <Name3>Town3</Name3>
      <Name4>Town4</Name4>
      <Name5>Town5</Name5>
      <Availability>8</Availability>
    </Test>
  </Import>
</ING_PNA_Import>
```

Finally, all this can be done without `<xsl:for-each>` which often is regularly used by newcomers in XSLT so used to iterative programming coming from general purpose languages not yet aware of the recursive template mapping of XSLT. Also, your *Availability* currently only takes from first *Branch* node. Below re-creates but think about mapping all values with corresponding *Branch* in last template:

**Alternative**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/PNAResponse">
    <ING_PNA_Import>            
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PriceAndAvailability"/>
    </ING_PNA_Import>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PriceAndAvailability">        
    <Import>
      <Test>
        <SKU><xsl:value-of select="@SKU"/></SKU>
        <VendorNumber><xsl:value-of select="VendorNumber"/></VendorNumber>
        <Price><xsl:value-of select="Price"/></Price>
        <MPN><xsl:value-of select="ManufacturerPartNumber"/></MPN>
        <ID><xsl:value-of select="Branch/@ID"/></ID>            
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Branch"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Branch[1]/Availability"/>
      </Test>
    </Import>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Branch">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Name', position())}">
       <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:element>                
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait! I believe my biggest problem was with using the different types of calls and how to use them.